# How to transpose a query result in ClickHouse ? ( Rows to Columns )

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-client

I am looking for an easy way to Transpose the Query Output in rows & columns (not one row in text by using Format Vertical ) .

My Query gives me an output like this :-

[image: Query Output]

And I want the output in the transposed format like this :-

[image: Desired Output]

I don't want to change any Data Type(s) and use it multiple times under a Parent Query .
Also, I am using DBeaver Client for the process.

I have went through the Pivot () , Unpivot() Functions used in SQL, SQL-Server but that doesnt work here.
I tried searching the Clickhouse Documentations but couldnt find anything more on this either .

Any help would be appreciated , Thanks !

Comment: Use if conditional functions - https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/conditional-functions#if - a example in this short video https://youtu.be/vaY5LQ7a_Dk?si=QrzQeRjtP0g_FgTh

Comment: I think this is currently not possible if the value of added_by_id and the columns are not a known set - its assumed that number of columns, types and names are known before query execution.

Comment: Not possible for now, but there is a feature request issue https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/50477

Comment: look to 
https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-queries-and-syntax/pivot-unpivot/